# What is the fastest way to earn tokens?

Tags: pokemon-tcg-online

So I've recently retaken up Pokemon TCGO, and have been lacking in the trainer token dept. So I've been wondering what is the most time/energy (no pun intended) efficient way to gain tokens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **Log in** each day.
- Play **one game** a day (the first gives more Tokens), making sure it lasts long enough to get Tokens.
- Look for **minigames on *pokemon.com***. Tokens are not limited to PTCGO, they're a site-wide feature (your login data is also the same across all of the Pokémon site). Some of those mini games are quite fun and they give varying amounts of Tokens, but generally more the first time you play.

Those are the only ways I'm aware of. Apart from these, just grind Tokens by playing, but this takes longer in terms of Tokens per time. The net gain is higher, of course, but it becomes inefficient after the first game.

Comment: As of current, first mini game without any score threshold yields 5 tokens. Any subsequent game, if beyond a certain score threshold, yields 3 tokens (the threshold varies per game). Also, it is important to note that pressing "play again" in game  will NOT trigger the token rewards. I had to restart the game by selecting the game from the mini-games page again.

Comment: Er... I take it back, yesterday I was trying to play minigames again and got totally random token drops varying from 1 to 8 tokens.

Answer (score 0):

To earn tokens, play Online games for 3 rounds then quit, and you will get a prize wheel item, which is commonly gold. Go to Bulbapedia and search Pokemon.com games or whatever and you can find what each game requires to earn tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Zoroarks Puzzle, takes 10 seconds minimum and give 3 tokens a run, limit or not, i dont know, i played ten times in a row, made 30 coins in 3 minutes

Answer (score -1):

Play 1 game a day and login 1ce every day 
Compete In available tournaments and play a couple of mini games first gives more